# Sort a file by the second column

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to sort a file alphabetically by the second column of each line, which contain uppercase names. An example file:

```
1:JOHN:Morgan:90:24
2:MIKE:Smith:95:11
3:JAYSON:Ty:99:9
4:TYLER:Edward:89:5
```

This is my bash script:

```
file="/home/here.txt"

while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
do
        tput cup $f1 0 ;echo  "$f2 $f1 $f3 $f4 $f5"
done <"$file"
```

I came up to here to sort them, but this only switches places of f2 with f1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to sort the file by second column of your file alphabetically:

```
file="/home/here.txt"
sort -t":" -k2 $file; # -t is delimeter and -k is column number to sort
```

Read about **sort** in man pages to get more info.

Comment: thank you so much. ive been looking everywhere for this